# Removing header and footer from UIWebView does not work always

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I want to remove the `header` and the `footer` from a `UIWebView`, which I load in a Controller of an application. I use the code:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
   NSString *js1 = @"document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].hide()";
   NSString *js2 = @"document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0].hide()";
   [webView performSelector:@selector(stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString)
             withObject:js1
             afterDelay:0.2];
   [webView performSelector:@selector(stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString)
             withObject:js2
             afterDelay:0.2];
}
```

I test it on `iPhone 5` and it works 95% correctly. I test it on `iPad2` and it works correctly only the first time showing the Controller (`UIWebView`) and then always with header and footer. What is the reason of it? Waht could be done to prevent the erroneous behavour?
I believe that the delay affects it, since it works always correctly when I debug it as I provoke an artificial delay.

Comment: are you sure the same webpage is rendering on the other devices as it renders on the iphone 5 device? I'm saying that perhaps the javascript of the web page changes to resize to the Phone/ipad size

Comment: I have not tested it on other devices. Irresprective of what happens on other devices, it should work on these two as well.

Comment: Just saying, I wonder if the underlying stuff is changing stuff up, that's all